# Not able to install bw2regional

Tags: brightway

The command `conda install -y -q -c cmutel bw2regional` in my Anaconda Prompt does not work to install `bw2regional`. The package is not found in the channel. I have not found another way to install it. Any idea?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you add your error message? The file is definitely there (https://anaconda.org/cmutel/bw2regional/files), and built for all OS architectures. I just tried a fresh install and it seemed to work fine in a fresh environment today.

Comment: Sure, thank you for your prompt response! 

`Solving environment: ...working... failed
PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:
  - bw2regional
  - pandarus[version='>=1.0.4']
  - rasterstats`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be that you need to need to list more channels, i.e.

```
conda install -c conda-forge -c cmutel -c konstantinstadler bw2regional
```

Comment: Can you mark the answer as accepted? Also, the documentation is a bit messy, see some examples here: https://github.com/cmutel/regionalized-lca-examples, and email me if you have questions.