# "Regionalization.ipynb is not trusted" issue with bw2regional

Tags: brightway

I managed to install bw2regional thanks to [this post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53340463/not-able-to-install-bw2regional)

but now when I want to run/import it in my notebook, I still get the error message:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bw2regional'

in my powershell miniconda prompt, the following line appears in parallel:

> 1 - Regionalization.ipynb is not trusted

Did I not do the installation correct?

Thanks in advance for any help

Edit:
Here are the packages I installed in my environment:

```
(condashell) PS C:\Users\reim> conda list
# packages in environment at C:\Users\reim\Miniconda3\envs\condashell:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
[I ommited some for claritys sake here]
brightway2                2.3                        py_2    cmutel
brotlipy                  0.7.0           py38h294d835_1001    conda-forge
bw2analyzer               0.9.4                      py_1    cmutel
bw2calc                   1.8.0                      py_0    cmutel
bw2data                   3.6.2                      py_0    cmutel
bw2io                     0.7.12                     py_0    cmutel
bw2parameters             0.6.6                      py_0    cmutel
bw2regional               0.5.2                      py_0    cmutel
bw_migrations             0.1                        py_0    cmutel
[I ommited some for claritys sake here]
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there are at least two things happening here.

1. You have a Jupyter notebook installed in a different environment than `bw2regional`

The reason I think this is that you can import `bw2regional`. I guess you should be able to run `conda install jupyter` in the same environment that you ran `conda install bw2regional`. If this sounds confusing, please read a bit on managing [conda environments](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html).

2. Your notebook is not trusted.

Not sure why this would be happening - hard to tell without knowing your OS, configuration, where you got the notebook, etc. But you can read about the [Jupyter security policy](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/security.html), maybe that helps.

Comment: Thank you Chris for your answer. 
Regarding the first part: It seems to me as if they are installed both/all in the same environment...
(I'm inserting the list in the original post)


Or am I missing something here?


Regarding the second point: Thank you, I was able to resolve this by entering
jupyter trust <path/notebook file>